# SQL server database on mac (replacing remote with localhost)

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a software application that is designed to save data to a remote sever, by using the following URL:

```
http://130.228.263.2/projectName.php
```

The application itself creates tables, stores data, etc... so I don't have to worry about that.

I have set up MySQL Server on my Mac as well as MySQLworkbench to see the database visually.

My question is: Should I simply replace the above URL with the following?

```
127.0.0.1.3306
```

to have the application data written to my Mac's database instead of the remote one, or are there any other steps (or different format for local host, etc...) that I should be taking as well?

Comment: That's an HTTP URL and has nothing to do with MySQL. Your application just calls this URL and the PHP script located on that *remote* server talks to its own database. So you would have to get a copy of this script, modify it so it talks to your *local* database and finally tell your application to call your *local* script at `http://127.0.0.1/projectName.php`.

Comment: Thanks André. So, the very first step is to get a copy of `projectName.php` script. I do have admin rights for that remote server, but is it possible to obtain this script remotely?

Comment: Remote into that server and just copy the file (and all its eventual dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mac Apache + PHP are installed by default, so it's not necessary to install anything. Just copy the php application to your local machine, adjust the db settings as MasterOdin wrote and you should be fine. Of course the php app must be accessible by your local Apache (you have to switch it on, via Internet Sharing in the system settings panel). In order to have a good starting point I recommend that you use MySQL Workbench to migrate your remote db to the local machine (see menu Database -> Migration Wizard).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the server can connect/view your local system (which is unlikely off the bat and would require more configuration), you would need to locally host the php file locally using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/), then open projectName.php and edit the MYSQL connection details within that file to point to 127.0.0.1.3306 (which should probably be 127.0.0.1:3306 as that last number is the port information?).

This would then write to your local DB setup.

Comment: Thanks MasterOdin. So, I should get MAMP for sure, even though I have set up a `MySQL Server` on my Mac? What _more configuration_ are you referring to, if I don't wanna rely on an external download like MAMP?

Comment: You need something like MAMP for the Apache and PHP runtimes such that it'll allow your computer to act like a webserver (accessible at localhost:8888 by default).

By "more configuration", you would have to make your computer be able to receive incoming traffic from the internet which would require you to open ports and muck about with your router. Far bigger hassle than just downloading the PHP script and using MAMP.